# How do you get rid of this className react-select warning?

Tags: react-select

`Warning: the behaviour of 'className' has changed between 2.0.0-beta.2 and 2.0.0-beta.3.
        You can now use className to specify the class name of the outer container, and classNamePrefix to enable our provided BEM class names for internal elements.
        The className prop will have no effect on internal elements when 2.0.0 is released.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got rid of the warning by adding a `classNamePrefix` prop.

`<Select classNamePrefix="foo" {...restOfTheProps} />`